# How to Clear stdin while reading stream of data?

Tags: c, unix, stdin

I have to create a c program that takes raw h264 frames from stdin and send it over the network via rtp.
The problem i am facing is that the video data from stdin gets read after the connection is created which can take unknown amount of time and the producer starts producing the video frames at stdin long before the connection is created.

i don't want to have delay in the streaming.
What i want to do is when the videohandler (that is reading the stdin) gets called, flush all the data that is present in the stdin and read the latest frame.

Comment: You either use two threads, or a non-blocking wait for both input stream and your outbound connection in an event loop (select, poll, epoll, io_uring).  I would read a chunk of data from input stream and just sync to next frame when you are ready to send output.

Comment: I am tempted to answer "not". Clearing the input stream is not a defined action and has not reliable effect. Many Q/A on StackOverflow describe how instead to deal with possibly remaining input.

Comment: One problem with "clearing an input stream" is that if `stdin` is redirected from file, you discard all the input.